# In Google+ if I +1 a post shared only with me then will my friends be able to see it

Tags: google-plus

Say one of my friends shared a picture only with me on Google+ and I +1 it. Will my other friends (or people in my circles) be able to see that post? In Facebook if any of my friends like a post which was shared with them and not with me then I can see that post with something like `<FRIEND NAME> likes <OTHER PERSON?'s picture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - privacy settings are always respected on Google+.